posterior covariance of a gaussian process
I'm currently studying gaussian processes.
In this framework we build "stochastic" functions f for instance $\mathbb{R}^N\mapsto\mathbb{R}$.
If I've got $M$ input $X_i\in\mathbb{R}^N$ gaussian processes are defined by a covariance function $K(x,x'):\mathbb{R}^N\times \mathbb{R}^N \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ such that a matrix $K$ is defined as $\forall M, \forall x, K_{ij} = K\left(X_i,X_j\right)$ is a symmetric positive semi-definite matrix.
optionally, we define also a mean vector $\mu \in \mathbb{R}^M$
Then $p\left(f|X_i\right)=\mathcal{N}_f\left(\mu,K\right)$
yet (through some lengthy computation) we can give the posterior probability of a new sample $f_*$ at a new $x_*$, given $N$ noisy observations $Y$ (usually the noise is modeled by $\mathcal{N}\left(0,\sigma^2 I\right)$)
$p(f_*|x_*,X_.,Y_.)=\mathcal{N}(\mu_{*|.},\Sigma_{*|.})$
with $\mu_{*|.}=K(x_*,X_.)(K(X_.,X_.)+\sigma^2 I)^{-1}(Y_.-\mu_.)+\mu_*$
and
$\Sigma_{*|.}=K(x_*,x_*)-K(x_*,X_.)(K(X_.,X_.)+\sigma^2 I)^{-1}K(X_.,x_*)$
(these formulae hold for $x_*$ being several samples)
I'd like the proof that $\Sigma_{*|.}$ is indeed a valid covariance matrix (symetric(obvious), positive, semi-definite).
An indirect proof is that it's the second argument of a valid multivariate distribution, thus the hypothesis must be true in order to integrate to 1 but I'm looking for a more direct proof.
Even the case where $x_*$ and $X_.$ are a single sample, is resisting me.

The object you are asking about is a vector (for one sample) or rectangular matrix so no covariance matrix.

I may have taken some liberties with notations: K(X.,X.) is M. x M. if I got M. observations, K(x∗,x∗) is M* x M* for M* new samples and K(x∗,X.) is M* x M., thus Σ∗|. is M* x M*

OK so you are interested in the special case where the number of observations is the same as the number of new samples? In general, however,  Σ∗| will be rectangular.

For your case, I think you can derive positive definiteness by using properties of the Schur complement. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement and https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~jean/schur-comp.pdf

@Jap88 Your idea seems OK: factorizing K defined by all samples (new and observations) using Schur complement it let appears Σ∗|. (actually Σ∗|. derivation uses Schur complement in the first place). Using K symmetry, positivity and semi-definity leads to the desired proof. May you make an answer of this? Thanks

This proof is derived from a hint by @Jap88, who suggested to factorize using Schur complement.
To be more specific, let's write the bigger matrix $K$ using all input $X$ (measure points and new $X$).
For compacity of notations, I will note:
$\Sigma_{ab}\check{=}K(X_a,X_b)$
where $a$ and $b$ denote sets of values (possibly singleton).
Besides, without loss of generality, I'm incorporating the term $\sigma^2I$ inside $\Sigma_{..}$
$K=\begin{pmatrix}
\Sigma_{..} & \Sigma_{.*} \\
\Sigma_{*.} & \Sigma_{**} 
\end{pmatrix}$
Let's use a LDU decomposition with Schur complement:
$K=\begin{pmatrix}
I & 0 \\
\Sigma_{*.}\Sigma_{..}^{-1} & I 
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
\Sigma_{..} & 0 \\
0 & \Sigma_{**}-\Sigma_{*.}\Sigma_{..}^{-1}\Sigma_{.*} 
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
I & \Sigma_{..}^{-1}\Sigma_{.*} \\
0 & I 
\end{pmatrix}$
Notice that the second diagonal block term is exactly the expression we want to examine.
Let's compute $X^TKX$ for any $X=\begin{pmatrix}X_.\\X_*\end{pmatrix}$, expanding the factorization and using $K$ symmetry:
$K=\left(X_.+\Sigma_{..}^{-1}\Sigma_{.*}X_*\right)^T\Sigma_{..}\left(X_.+\Sigma_{..}^{-1}\Sigma_{.*}X_*\right)+X_*^T\left(\Sigma_{**}-\Sigma_{*.}\Sigma_{..}^{-1}\Sigma_{.*}\right)X_*$
Yet $K$ is symmetric semi-definite positive. Thus the above expression is positive.
As $X$ is chosen arbitrarily we can take chose $X_*$ arbitrarily and make $X_. = -\Sigma_{..}^{-1}\Sigma_{.*}X_*$
Thus
$X_*^T\left(\Sigma_{**}-\Sigma_{*.}\Sigma_{..}^{-1}\Sigma_{.*}\right)X_*\ge0$
Which complete the proof that, under the given asumption, $X_*^T\left(\Sigma_{**}-\Sigma_{*.}\Sigma_{..}^{-1}\Sigma_{.*}\right)X_*$ is symmetric semi-definite positive, thus a valid covariance matrix.
